# ImportError: cannot import name 'Stylesheet' from 'bs4.element'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get some links after accessing a website. I'm getting the following error when importing BeautifulSoup.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/User/Python/CF.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\CP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Users\CP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Stylesheet' from 'bs4.element' (C:\Users\CP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py)
```

Here's how I installed it.
`pip install beautifulsoup4` then cd to the directory and run `Python setup.py install`

I've tried reinstalling it as well.

There is nothing much to the code. It works fine when I remove `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.facebook.com/"
r = requests.get(URL)
```

I've also tried changing the name of the file from Report.py to CF.py

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with python 3.8. I have the same problem with Python3.8.6. So you can change your intrepreter or uninstall Python3.8 and install another version.